# http compression for post data

Tags: http-compression

I use php's ob_gzhandler for getting gzipped content. 
In request headers,  **Accept-Encoding:** gzip, deflate.  
In response headers,  **Content-Encoding:** gzip  
I want to know if a post data from browser in the page to server will be compressed in any form.

Answer (score 0):

Only the HTTP response will be compressed.